# Socket.io - is it possible to build something other than a chatting app with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have just started using socket.io and I was doing some research and it seems like all of the results are chat and messaging apps.  So my question is, is there more use to socket.io than a chatting app, like could you say create a Facebook clone and have a login/sign up built using socket.io?

Comment: Please use your imagination as to what can be done using socket.io or realtime data. https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-examples-of-apps-using-socket-io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

socket.io supports a two-way communication channel between a browser web page and a server.  There are zillions of things one could do with that.  While chat is an obvious use that everyone understands (and thus why sample apps show that), socket.io is a communications channel and can be used for literally almost anything.  Some ideas:

1. You start a long running task on the server (that might take 15 minutes to run).  Meanwhile, as the server makes progress, it sends regular progress notifications back to the web page over a socket.io connection and thus the web page can show the precise progress without having to poll the server.
2. I have a home automation server that monitors a number of temperatures around the house and controls a few electronic devices based on those temperatures (like attic fans).  When I got to the web page for that home automation server, it shows a live set of readings for all the temperature probes because the automation server pushes temperature updates to the web page live as they change.
3. You are a currency trader and you want to watch live changes in currency fluctuations.  You go to a web page that gets live updates from a server over socket.io.
4. In a Facebook-like app, a developer could use a socket.io connection to keep the browser status up-to-date for who is online, who's not online and to deliver live updates to the feed.
5. In a sports web page, you could open a page for a specific baseball game and get live updates of the progress of the game via a socket.io connection.

The general theme here is that any time the server has some sort of live data that it wants to "push" to the client as soon as the data changes without waiting for the client to "poll" for the data, a socket.io connection works great for that.  Without the socket.io connection, the web page would have to regular poll the server to ask for the latest data which is both not live and not efficient for client, server or bandwidth usage.